# mSlider.startIndeterminate() not working

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm switching to the Slider API for indeterminate progress bars. I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/slider) tutorial. Everything works, except the fact the indeterminate progress bar doesn't appear.

The end result is supposed to look something like this:

[image: gif from google glass developement page]

Here is the activity that fetches some videos, while an indeterminate slider is shown waiting for the results.

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    //...
    private Slider.Indeterminate mIndeterminate;
    private CardScrollView mCardScroller;
    private Slider mSlider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        keyword = (String)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("keywords");
        mCardScroller = new CardScrollView(this);
        mCardScroller.setAdapter(new CardAdapter(createCards(this)));
        mSlider = Slider.from(mCardScroller);
        setContentView(mCardScroller);
        new LoadAllVideos().execute();
    }
    private ArrayList<CardBuilder> createCards(Context context){
        ArrayList<CardBuilder> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        cards.add(new CardBuilder(context, CardBuilder.Layout.MENU)
              .setText("Loading...")
              .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        return cards;
    }
        //...
}
```

In my LoadAllVideos (that extends AsyncTask ..) I have

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
    Log.w("progressbar", "start");
    mIndeterminate = mSlider.startIndeterminate();
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String url){
    Log.w("progressbar", "stop");
    mIndeterminate.hide();
    Intent res = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
    res.putExtra("videos", videos);
    startActivity(res);
    finish();
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Slider` API relies on the `View` you used when initializing it to be `VISIBLE` so that it can properly recycle sliders that were started from Views that got hidden.

Could you try starting your load video task in the `onResume` callback instead of `onCreate`? At that point the `CardScrolLView` you're using should have been attached to a `Window` and be rendered `VISIBLE`.